# Yii ajax form submission and update?

Tags: php, jquery, yii, yii-components

I'm trying to implement a commenting system on my web project, I'm extremely new to Yii. I want the user to be able to submit a comment, which in turn updates the database, and re-renders ALL the posts' comments (NB: I do not want the whole page refresh).

I'm trying to achieve this using `CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton`, but I can't seem to get it to even make the call. I have no idea how to check if the call is even being made.

My current code is as follows:

`_questionComment` - this is partially rendered within the 'Browse' view

```
<div class="form">

<?php

    $form = $this -> beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id' => 'question-answer-form',
        'enableClientValidation'=>true,
        'clientOptions'=>array(
            'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
        ),
    ));

    $response = new QuestionAnswerForm;
?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php 
            echo $form->labelEx($response, 'link');
            echo $form->textField($response, 'link');
            echo $form->error($response, 'link');
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php 
            echo $form->labelEx($response, 'description');
            echo $form->textField($response, 'description');
            echo $form->error($response, 'description');
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
         <?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Reply', 'comment', array(
             'update'=>'#comments',
             'type'=>'POST',
        )); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div>
```

`QuestionController/actionComment()` - should handle the ajax request

```
public function actionComment()
        {
            if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
            {
                //current user has posted a response
                if(isset($_POST['QuestionAnswerForm']))
                {
                    $response = new QuestionAnswerForm;
                    $response->attributes = $_POST['QuestionAnswerForm'];
                    //answer form has passed inspection
                    if($response->validate())
                    {
                        //save new answer to database
                        $newAnswer = new QuestionAnswer;
                        $newAnswer->link = $response->link;
                        $newAnswer->description = $response->description;
                        $newAnswer->question_id = Yii::app()->getRequest()->getQuery('id');
                        $newAnswer->user_id = Yii::app()->user->getId();

                        //adds a timestamp using a default timezone 'GMT'
                        $newAnswer->timestamp = Timestamp::getCurrentTimeStamp();

                        $newAnswer->save();
                    }     
                }
            }
        }
```

`browse` - This is where the comments are rendered. After the user submits their comment, I want the browse page to partially render all the comments again. I tried to achieve this using the 'update' parameter in the ajaxSubmitButton.

```
<?php
/* 
 * @var $this QuestionController
 * @var $question Question
 * @var $answers QuestionAnswer
 */

    echo "<h1>" . $question['name'] . "</h1>";
    echo "<h3>" . $question['description'] . "</h3>"
?>

<? $this->renderPartial('_renderComments', array('answers'=>$answers)); ?>
<? $this->renderPartial('_questionComment'); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please check the below link.hope this will help you.

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/49/update-content-in-ajax-with-renderpartial/